# How to trigger execute to export csv file?

Tags: sql-server

i have no idea for how to create trigger and how to execute trigger in sql server 2008
Please help How to trigger execute to export csv file?
 Select * from user_Registrition;
 user_Registrition table to create trigger and trigger excute to all user_Registrition data export in csv file

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CSV_User_Registration] 
   ON [dbo].[User_Registration] 
   FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @FileName varchar(50),
@bcpCommand varchar(8000)

SET @FileName = 'c:\query_result' + replace(replace(convert(varchar(20), getdate()),' ','_'),':','-') + '.csv'

select @FileName

SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "select char(34)+string_column+char(34)+char(44)+char(34)+ convert(varchar(10),Int_or_date_column) + char(34) from [dbo].[User_Registration]  " queryout "'
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FileName + '" -U sa -P Password1$ -d CCMS -c'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand

END
GO

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you've taken, does it fail silently, does it fail with an error? Do you get unexpected results? Can you tell us what happens when you run the code you've added?

Comment: how to run trigger in sql server 2008 i have don't idea for exceute trriger i have create successfully trigger but how to excute trigger in quey window??

Comment: How to execute the trigger? Insert or update a row in the table. Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes trigger execute and file not exports error console:- SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name [dbo].[User_Registration].
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 8180
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
NULL

Comment: An error! Finally! Thank you :). If you inspect the contents of @bcpCommand before the exec, will that command run from the command line? You may be missing the database name. p.s. you really should edit your question and add the error to it.

Comment: @bcp command in add user name password and database name then execute trigger ERROR:- Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.
update post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DECLARE @FileName varchar(50),@bcpCommand varchar(8000)
SET @FileName = 'D:\USER_SETUP' + replace(replace(CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),3)+' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),8),'/','_'),':','-') + '.csv'

SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "select * from CCMS.DBO.USER_SETUP" queryout "'
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FileName + '" -T -SESPACE-WEB\SQLEXPRESS -c -t,'

PRINT @bcpCommand
EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand

Comment: Instead of double replacement, consider writing a date string such as 
... 'D:\USER_SETUP' + FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm') + '.csv'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you understand the concept of a trigger?

Are you simply trying to export a table to CSV? In management studio, you can right click on the database -> Tasks -> Export. From there, you'll be able to export the table to a CSV file.

Comment: i use sql server 2008 and not prompt to export csv file. just create trigger and trigger execeute to export csv file. trigger in include export csv file code how to do that?

Comment: The way I showed is the way it's done. What do you mean by "not prompt to export csv". Could you not find the option? A trigger is created on a table and is triggered either by updates or deletions. I don't think that is what you're after.

Comment: yes trigger either by updates then user registration table data export in csv file

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific in your question as I've been having a hard time understanding exactly what you need.

Comment: i have put trigger in post

Comment: how to run trigger in sql server 2008 i have don't idea for exceute trriger i have create successfully trigger but how to excute trigger in quey window??